# How to rewrite SQL query without IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Schema:

```
Table A: AID(PK), RECEIVE_DATE
Table B: BID(PK), AID(FK), MESSAGE, ITEMID, ITEMTYPE
```

Tables A-to-B have a one-to-many mapping.

Here is a working SQL query (in SQL Server) to find out the latest message grouped by ITEMID i.e for different ITEMID (of ITEMTYPE say as 'XYZ').

```
 SELECT 
     b.MESSAGE, b.ITEMID
 from a
 inner join b on b.aid = a.aid AND b.ITEMTYPE = 'XYZ'
 where a.receive_date in (select max(receive_date)
                                             from a a1
                                             inner join b b1 on b1.aid = a1.aid   
                                             where b1.itemid = b.itemid
                                             );
```

How can we rewrite this SQL query without `IN` clause [also without rownumber concept in use], as ORACLE is having restriction for IN clause. Getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 for above expression.

Comment: Are you sure this is the query produced the error. AFAIK, that restriction is applied only when values are passed in `IN` clause like `a.receive_date in ('2017-01-01','2017-02-01',..)`

Comment: And you can simply change `IN` to `=` and get the same result, instead of rewrite query using `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Prdp Maybe the error is being caused by having an intermediate query inside an `IN` expression which has too many records.  Just a guess.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - It isn't a problem in Sql Server not sure about Oracle though..

Comment: @prdp Yes it is throwing the exception, but not for the limit of 1k, even for 2k-3k data no error is coming but when it crossing data more than 10, then above exception is coming.  SQL server is not having any IN clause restriction.

Comment: There are two form of `IN` clause - value based and sub-query based. The restriction only applies to they 1st one. 2nd one is silently rewritten onto a join by the optimizer. I do not believe, that your query really returns that error. You might get an error when the sub-query returned more that one column - but it is a semantic error. Your sub-query returns only a single value so `IN` can be even replaced by pure `=`. I think you "anonymised" the query before posting and the real problem is somewhere else. ps: you can avoid self-joins by using analytic functions.

Comment: If one of your tables has > 1000 partitions then the ORA-01795 may be related to a bug referred to here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45050530/430567 (also mentions NO_EXPAND_TABLE hint which you could try to verify if this is the issue),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear to me why you are getting `ORA-01795`.  Your subquery only selects a max value, which should be a single value.  In addition, the 1000 value limit only applies to a list of literals, not a subquery.  In any case, you could rephrase this query using a join instead of `WHERE IN`:

```
SELECT 
    b.MESSAGE,
    b.ITEMID
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON b.aid = a.aid AND b.ITEMTYPE = 'XYZ'
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        b1.itemid,
        MAX(receive_date) AS max_receive_date
    FROM a a1
    INNER JOIN b b1
        ON b1.aid = a1.aid   
    GROUP BY b1.itemid
) t
    ON b.itemid = t.itemid
WHERE a.receive_date = t.max_receive_date
```

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS` and `IN` tend to be interchangeable, and `EXISTS` performs better in some engines (not sure about Oracle) due to the fact that it returns true on the first match, rather than generating a subset and checking against that.  I'm not familiar with Oracle, but I imagine you could use the following to circumvent your 1000 row limit on `IN`:

```
SELECT 
    b.MESSAGE, b.ITEMID
from a
inner join b on b.aid = a.aid AND b.ITEMTYPE = 'XYZ'
where exists (
    SELECT 1
    from a a1
    inner join b b1 on b1.aid = a1.aid   
    where b1.itemid = b.itemid
    having MAX(a1.receive_date) = a.receive_date
)
```